# 目覚まし音も、"1分"遅れに鳴るのではなく、時間が来たら鳴るようにする方法について

Tags: javascript

下記のソースコードは、デジタルの目覚まし時計の目覚ましをセットして、時間が来るとデジタル時計は消え、目覚まし音とともに"アナログ時計"が現れるように設定したものですが、目覚まし音はアナログ時計が現れて"1分後"に鳴り始めます。セレクトの表示は、アナログ時計が現れるのと同時に切り替わります。どうすれば、目覚まし音も時間通りに切り替わるか、ご教示ください。

なお、音は出ないように設定しています。

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
        <HTML>
        <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">

        <bgsound id="bgm" src="２２２.mid" loop="-1">

        <TITLE>デジタル時計がアナログ時計に！</TITLE> 


        <!--- 時計 JavaScript ---> 
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        //アラームフラグを初期化する。
        var flg =0;

        //時刻更新＆アラームチェックファンクション
        function timeCheck(){
            //時刻を取得。
            Now = new Date();
            Hour = Now.getHours();
            Min = Now.getMinutes();
            Sec = Now.getSeconds();

           // "分"と"秒"が1桁の場合、頭に0を付けて2桁で表示する指定
                if(Hour <= 9) { 
                               Hour = "\u0020" + Hour; 
        }        
        　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                               Min = "0" + Min; 
        }
                if(Sec <= 9) { 
                               Sec = "0" + Sec; 
        }


            //時刻を表示。
            document.sampleForm.dspTime.value=Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;



            //時刻をチェック。

        if((flg == 1)&&(document.sampleForm.alarmH.value == Hour)&&(document.sampleForm.alarmM.value == Min)){
        document.getElementById('bgCol').value="３３３.wav", selectBgm(document.getElementById('bgCol')),
        document.getElementById('star_clock').style.visibility="hidden", document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
        }
 }

        //アラームフラグ変更ファンクション

    function changeFlg(){
      if(flg == 0){
        //アラーム未設定時、  
        flg =1;
        　document.sampleForm.setAlarm.value=" alarmOFF ";
          document.getElementById("bgCol").value="";
          selectBgm(document.getElementById('bgCol'));
      }else{
        //アラーム設定済み時、
        flg =0;
         document.sampleForm.setAlarm.value=" alarm ON ";
         document.getElementById("bgms").reset();
         selectBgm(document.getElementById('bgCol'));
         document.getElementById('star_clock').style.visibility="visible";
         document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        }

　　//次の更新をセットする。
      setInterval(timeCheck,100);
              window.onload = timeCheck;
        //-->
        </SCRIPT>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
           function selectBgm(e){
            var selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
                document.getElementById("bgCol").style.background=e[selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;
                bgm.src= e[selectedIndex ].value; 
                document.getElementById("bgCol").value=e[selectedIndex].value;
        }
         //-->
        </script>
        </head>


        <BODY color="gold" bgcolor="black">


        <div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">
            <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
                <div style="position:relative">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
                <div style="position:relative">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
                <div style="position:relative">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
                <div style="position:relative">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
                <div style="position:relative">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(){
            "use strict";

        function $(sel)
        {
            return document.getElementById(sel);
        }   

        function $$(sel)
        {
            if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
            {
                return document.getElementsByName(sel);
            }
            return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
        }

        var dCol = '00ff00', //date colour.
            sCol = 'ff0000', //seconds colour.
            mCol = '008000', //minutes colour.
            hCol = '008000', //hours colour.
            fCol = '0000ff', //face color
            ClockHeight = 40,
            ClockWidth = 40,
            ClockFromMouseY = 0,
            ClockFromMouseX = 100,
            d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            date = new Date(),
            day = date.getDate(),
            year = date.getYear() + 1900;

        var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
        var D = TodaysDate.split('');
        var H = '...';
            H = H.split('');
        var M = '....';
            M = M.split('');
        var S = '.....';
            S = S.split('');
        var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
            font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            size = 1,
            speed = 0.6;
            Face = Face.split(' ');
        var n = Face.length;
        var a = size * 10;
        var ymouse = 0,
            xmouse = 0,
            scrll = 0,
            props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
            props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
        var Split = 360 / n;
        var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
        var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
        var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
        var HandY = -7,
            HandX = -2.5,
            step = 0.06,
            currStep = 0,
            y = [],
            x = [],
            Y = [],
            X = [],
            Dy = [],
            Dx = [],
            DY = [],
            DX = [];
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            y[i] = 0;
            x[i] = 0;
            Y[i] = 0;
            X[i] = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
        {
            Dy[i] = 0;
            Dx[i] = 0;
            DY[i] = 0;
            DX[i] = 0;
        }

        var wrapper = $('clock');
        var html = ''
        // Date wrapper

        html = '';

        for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
        {
            html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
        }

        $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
        // Face wrapper
        html = '';

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
        }

        $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
        // Hours wrapper
        html = '';

        for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
        {
            html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
        } 

        $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
        // Minute wrapper

        html = '';

        for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)

        {

            html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';

        } 

        $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;



        // Seconds wrapper

        html = '';

        for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)

        {

            html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';

        } 

        $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;



        // Mouse move event handler

        function Mouse(evnt) 

        {

            if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')

            {

                ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;

                xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;

            }
            else
            {
                ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
                xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
            }
        }

        document.onmousemove = Mouse;

        function ClockAndAssign() 

        {
            var time = new Date();
            var secs = time.getSeconds();
            var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
            var mins = time.getMinutes();
            var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
            var hr = time.getHours();
            var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;

            $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
            $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
            $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
            $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
            $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var F = $$('Face')[i];
                F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
                F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
            {
                var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
                HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
                HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
            {
                var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
                ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
                ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
            {
                var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
                SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
                SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
            {
                var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
                DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
                DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
            }
            currStep -= step;
        }

        function Delay() 
        {
            scrll = 0;
            Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
            Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
            for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
                Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
                Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
            }
            y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
            x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
            for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
                x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
            }
            ClockAndAssign();
            setTimeout(Delay, 20);
        }
        Delay();
        }());
        </script>


            <form id="bgms" style="text-align:right">
               <SELECT id="bgCol" style="background:#87cefa"; onchange="selectBgm(this);">
                 <OPTION style="background:silver" value="" >選曲(停止)</OPTION>
                 <OPTION style="background:#87cefa" value="２２２.mid" selected>２２２(クラシック)</OPTION>
                 <OPTION style="background:yellowgreen" value="３３３.wav">３３３(目覚まし音)</OPTION>
               </SELECT>
            </form>

        <FORM  NAME="sampleForm" style="text-align:center">
        　<font id="star_clock">
        <INPUT id="Alarmy" type="text"STYLE="color:deeppink; background-color:black; font-size:25px; border:none;" size=7 NAME="dspTime">
        　</font>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        　<div>
        ★
        <INPUT type="text" name="alarmH" size=2 value="00">
        <INPUT type="text" name="alarmM" size=2 value="00">
        <INPUT type="button" id="setAlarm" name="setAlarm" value=" alarm ON " onClick="changeFlg();">
        ★
        　</div>
        </FORM>

        </BODY>
        </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

時計のjavascriptの"時刻をチェック"のところを、
下記のように"flg=0(又は,1);"以外の数字(＊2でも,2.5でも,３でも,又は-1でも,
-1.5でも可能のようです)を付け加えれば、目覚ましの設定時刻と同時に
目覚まし音が鳴りました。

(追加箇所)

```
    //時刻をチェック。
if((flg == 1)&&(document.sampleForm.alarmH.value == Hour)&&(document.sampleForm.alarmM.value == Min)){
document.getElementById('bgCol').value="３３３.wav", selectBgm(document.getElementById('bgCol')),
document.getElementById('star_clock').style.visibility="hidden", document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
flg=-1;
}
```

どうして"flg=0(又は,1);"以外の数字だったら、目覚ましの設定時刻と同時に
目覚まし音が鳴るのか，この理由はわかっていませんが。

Comment: 回答というより質問に見えていたので文の構成を変更させていただきました。 / チェックマークがついていることで解決済みと思われるでしょうし、あなたの追加の疑問に気づかない方も多いかと思います。そのことをご承知であれば構いませんが、必要なら別の質問として投稿することも検討していただいたほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: 文の構成を変更していただきましてありがとうございます。
かなり日にちが経っていますから、気づかれないかもしれませんね。

下記のサイトに、私と似たような疑問をお持ちの方がいまして、
その方の質問の回答でヒントを得て、"flag=-1"を付け加えたところ
うまくいった次第です。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486428/why-does-my-alarmclock-script-stop-working

Answer (score 0):

まず最初に、

問題が起こっているソースを全て張るのではなく、質問のある箇所、調べる箇所に対してのみ抽出すると、問題の解消ができると思います。例えば時計のデザインが変わったと同時にアラームがなれば良いのですから、

何かのイベントが発生したと同時にアラームがなるかどうかを検証されてから、
デザインなどを実装されるのが良いでしょう。

なお、bgsound要素はInternetExplorerでのみ動作するタグですので、ご注意ください。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。ソースは、疑問と連結していますので
貼らなければ分からないのです。問題は、時計のjavascript内の”//時刻をチェック”内にあると思いますが、なぜ目覚まし音が"1分遅れて鳴る"のか分からないのです。BGMのセレクトの表示は、目覚ましの設定時刻が来ると変わるのにです。

Comment: 一度ブラウザのF12を押してデバッグモードで起動されて動作の確認をされることをすすめます。
問題の起こっている箇所は色々ありますが、致命的なのは、アラーム時刻が来ると20ミリ秒ごとにfunction selectBgm(e)が呼び出されていることです。
実装している内容が非常に雑多な状態なので、一度もっと簡素なコードを書いて、ボタンを押したらbgmが変わるかどうかだけのコードを書いておくのが良いのではないでしょうか。私からは以上です。

Comment: 素人ですので、問題箇所が見えません。
BGMのセレクトの表示が変わったら,目覚まし音が鳴る，という単純なものではないのですね。
簡素なコードはありますので、そちらを数日後に送ります。